# Is there any way to burn into disc that is not empty?

Tags: burning, disc

My DVD failed at 1% during the burn process due to a power failure.  Can I burn that disc again, or do I need new one?

Answer (score 4):

Probably not.

Is it an eraseable disc (ie, [RW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD+RW))? If so, then you should be able to erase it and try again.

If not, were you using [packet-writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_writing) (ie, using the disc like a floppy disk where you can copy and paste files into whenever you want and they are burned as you go)? If so, then perhaps you can continue (though you’ll probably lose the space that was used by previous files).

If it was a full-disc burn on a non-erasable disc, then *maybe* you could get lucky if you have a closed [session](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28CD%29), but open disc, but in all likelihood no, you probably won’t be able to use it (at least not in any way that makes it worth the trouble or cost of just junking the disc), sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Just tried to copy paste a file into a used disk in windows 8 burner and re burn it. it turns out that it worked!

Note : I burned using the default win 8 (or 8.1 to be exact) burner and reburn it with the same burner.

I'm fully awake to recognize my CD-R

Comment: @Ramhound It's a CD-R. Otherwise I won't bother post here. Think, try, and ask before you downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound **have you tried to do it before you insisted?** (under win 8.1 burner)

Comment: @Ramhound well, we have different outcomes then. I was burned the cd > ejected it > burned some other cds > inserts the first cd > re burned the first cd with a new data. I think I didn't left the first session opening that way. Idk

Comment: @Ramhound the second / bottom one. The non-live version.

Comment: if it failed at '1%' perhaps it's possible nothing ever actually made it to disc and you were still filling the write buffer up.